# Not throwing PHP exception when switching MongoDB primary

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a MongoDB 2.2 replicaset setup (2 nodes), and connect to test using PHP, e.g.

```
$mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://192.168.1.1:27017,192.168.1.2:27017", 
                        array("replicaSet" => "testrs", 
                              "safe" => TRUE));
$db = $mongo->test;
$collection = $db->dump;

while (true) {

    echo "Result: " . 
            $collection->insert(array( "ts" => time() ));

    sleep(10);
}
```

During the middle of the execution, when I `stepDown` from the primary node, I found the insert stop working but the **echo** stil give me **1**, so no exception was throw, any issue with my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php), `insert` throws exceptions only when `safe` option is set:

> Throws MongoCursorException if the "safe" option is set and the insert
>   fails. (Version 1.0.1+)
>
> Throws MongoCursorTimeoutException if the "safe" option is set and the
>   operation takes longer than MongoCursor::$timeout milliseconds to
>   complete. This does not kill the operation on the server, it is a
>   client-side timeout.

Set `safe` option and you should be able to see the exception thrown.